# Jupyter Notebook: save all images to svg by program

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When I click the `Download as markdown` in the menu,

[image]

it will give me zip file with `.md`, `.png`, '.svg'

[image]

Note: I use `set_matplotlib_formats('png', 'svg')`, so the download file returns 2 image file formats.

Now, I want to save all the images in this notebook into svg by program (i.e., writing Python script), how can I do it? Maybe something like

```
save_images_to_svg('this_notebook.ipynb')
# and it will save all images to '.\images\*.svg'
```

---

What I know so far:

The link for `Download as markdown` is at [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/f81fb46ff68323f9652d638a325e9ccc46f62e83/notebook/static/notebook/js/menubar.js#L196)

```
    this.element.find('#download_markdown').click(function () {
        that._nbconvert('markdown', true);
    });
```

It further binds to the `_nbconvert` at [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/f81fb46ff68323f9652d638a325e9ccc46f62e83/notebook/static/notebook/js/menubar.js#L133)

```
MenuBar.prototype._nbconvert = function (format, download) {
    download = download || false;
    var notebook_path = utils.encode_uri_components(this.notebook.notebook_path);
    var url = utils.url_path_join(
        this.base_url,
        'nbconvert',
        format,
        notebook_path
    ) + "?download=" + download.toString();

    this._new_window(url);
    };
```

This means that the notebook sends a request to the backend to do the conversion.

I don't know where it is, but it seems like [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/179bb24fbf79d153812858126127a91431da3319/notebook/nbconvert/handlers.py), because it has a `respond_zip` method.

I think a quick hack is simply to download the file using python with the url from `MenuBar.prototype._nbconvert`.

Answer (score 1):

Create the plot using matplotlib and save the image with the following command. It works in Sage 8.1 (windows). You will find the figures where your .ipynb file is located.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.arange(-2 * numpy.pi, 2 * numpy.pi, 0.1)
func = numpy.sin(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(3.3, 3.3))    # inches
plt.plot(x, func, linewidth=2.0, color='blue') 

plt.savefig('demo1.svg')
plt.savefig('demo1.pdf')
plt.savefig('demo1.eps')
plt.savefig('demo1.tif')
plt.show()
# plt.close()
```